# how to label a three dimensional data in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a three dimensional data to fit a tensorflow.js model on it. But the code I have tried is not showing any value nor any error. I don't know how to exactly assign a label to a feature. How I am supposed to do this with three dimensional data ? The complete code with model is attached below

**Update**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
    import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
    import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isTfReady: false,
        };
      }
      init() {
        const model = tf.sequential({
            layers: [
                tf.layers.dense({
                    inputShape: [784],
                    units: 32,
                    activation: "relu"
                }),
                tf.layers.dense({
                    units: 10,
                    activation: "softmax"
                })
            ]
        });

    model.compile({
        optimizer: "sgd",
        loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
        metrics: ["accuracy"] 
    });  

    featureTensor = tf.tensor2d([[1],[2],[4]])
    featureTensor1 = tf.tensor2d([[2],[1],[3]])
    featureTensor2 = tf.tensor2d([[3],[2],[1]])  

    featuresTensor = tf.stack([featureTensor, featureTensor1, featureTensor2]) 
    const labelArray = ["standing", "sitting"]
    // {standing: 0, sitting: 1}
    const mapIndexLabel = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({...labelArray}).map(([a, b]) => [b, +a])) 
    labelsTensor = tf.onehot([0, 1, 1], numberOfUniqueLabels) // numberOfUniqueLabels = 2 in this case

    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
      logs.acc = parseFloat((logs.acc * 100).toFixed(2));
      logs.loss = parseFloat((logs.loss * 100).toFixed(3));
      console.log("Accuracy", logs.acc);
    }
    // Train for 5 epochs with batch size of 32.
    model
        .fit(featuresTensor, labelsTensor, {
            epochs: 10,
            batchSize: 32,
            callbacks: {
                onBatchEnd
            }
        })
        .then(info => {
          this.setState({info: info })
          history = model.fit(featuresTensor, labelsTensor, {
            });
            console.log("Final accuracy", info.history.acc);
        });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {

    await tf.ready();
    this.init()
    // Signal to the app that tensorflow.js can now be used.
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {info} = this.state; 
    return (
      <View style={styles.output}>
        {info && info.history.acc.map(i=>(<Text>{i}</Text>))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  output: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  //   alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
})
```

Comment: `tf.tensor3d([[1],[2],[4]])` will throw an error. `[[1],[2],[4]]` is a shape of a 2d tensor. The shape is `[3, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

> I have a three dimensional data to fit a tensorflow.js

It is not a three dimensional data, it is a two dimensional data. `tf.tensor3d([[1],[2],[4]])` will fail in constructing a 3d tensor, thus throwing an error. To constructor the feature tensors, `tf.tensor` can be used - it will infer the shape from the data itself; alternatively you can use tf.tensor2d for easy readability.

```
featureTensor = tf.tensor2d([[1],[2],[4]])
```

The second thing to mention is that there needs to be a flatten layer before the last layer to allow the model output to be of one dimension.

As for the callBack, it needs to be called given a certain event.

```
const model = tf.sequential({
            layers: [
                tf.layers.dense({
                    inputShape: [3, 1],
                    units: 32,
                    activation: "relu"
                }),
                tf.layers.flatten(),
                tf.layers.dense({
                    units: 2,
                    activation: "softmax"
                })
            ]
        });

    model.compile({
        optimizer: "sgd",
        loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
        metrics: ["accuracy"] 
    });  

    featureTensor = tf.tensor2d([[1],[2],[4]])
    featureTensor1 = tf.tensor2d([[2],[1],[3]])
    featureTensor2 = tf.tensor2d([[3],[2],[1]])  

    featuresTensor = tf.stack([featureTensor, featureTensor1, featureTensor2]) 
    const labelArray = ["standing", "sitting"]
    // {standing: 0, sitting: 1}
    const mapIndexLabel = {standing: 0, sitting: 1}
    labelsTensor = tf.oneHot([0, 1, 1], 2) // numberOfUniqueLabels = 2 in this case

    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
      logs.acc = parseFloat((logs.acc * 100).toFixed(2));
      logs.loss = parseFloat((logs.loss * 100).toFixed(3));
      console.log("Accuracy", logs.acc);
    }

model.summary()
    // Train for 5 epochs with batch size of 32.
featuresTensor.print()
labelsTensor.print()
 hist = await  model
        .fit(featuresTensor, labelsTensor, {
 callbacks: {onEpochEnd: onBatchEnd }
 })
console.log(hist)
```

Comment: I did but it is still blank... no output

Comment: Maybe that there are other errors in the model definition. Can you please update your question with the model itself ?

Comment: Model is same I were working before.... Well, I updated the question

Comment: I am right, it can't work. Your model is expecting a feature tensor of shape [784]. But you are passing a tensor of shape [3, 1]. I think if you open your console, you will see error indicating why it is not working

Comment: How to select input shape's value... I have to add almost 200 features more

Comment: The model inputShape must match your feature shape. If you want to train features of shape [3, 1], the inputShape must be [3, 1]. The number of features (200) does not matter. Because when you will stack all your features, you will have a tensor of shape [numberOfFeatures, 3, 1] and it is what model.fit is expecting

Comment: Console is still blank..... Any useful resource regarding `tensorflow.js` rather then official site of it....I'm sure I'm gonna face many more problems with it ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203748/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-sarah).